# Delete elements from Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to delete all the elements from a Numpy array except the last element and return the Numpy array.
For eg: arr = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
Output should be:: arr = [11]

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Maybe you can try arr[-1:]

Answer (score 1):

We can slice using -1 to start from the last item.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) 
last_arr = arr[-1:]
print (last_arr)
```

gives

```
[11]
```

We can use `arr[-1]` to get the value of the last element, but it gives us the value `11` and not as an array `[11]` as you want. We can then create a new array, but this is a longer way to do it.

Comment: For sure getting the last part of the array is a better idea than creating a new one, so you deserve my upvote. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
arr[-1] # This is the last element
```

so you can assign something this way:

```
arr = np.array([arr[-1]]) # A numpy.array containing only the last element of the other one
```

Otherwise, if you only want a `list` containing the last element:

```
new = [arr[-1]]
```